# How to count the frequency of observation by group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame sorted and grouped by the highest value (column Indicator-Value) per year. It gives me the countries with the highest Indicator values per year. I have 212 countries in my dataframe and I have years 1960 to 2014.

For the next step, I want to see which 5 countries were in the Top 10 for the most years out of all available years. So, for all countries, I want to keep a counter of how many times they were in the top 10 for each year and see which had the higher amount of top 10 showings. My desired output is a count of how many times a country appears on the top ten list for each year. How can I do that? Here is what I have so far:

```
gp = (Emissions_C_CO2.sort_values(['Year', 'Indicator_Value'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby(['Year', 'Country_Code']).head(10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
result = (
    Emissions_C_CO2.sort_values('Indicator_Value', ascending=False)
        .groupby('Year').head(10)
        .groupby('Country_Name').size()
        .sort_values(ascending=False)
)
```

Explanation:

- Sort the dataframe by `Indicator_Value` in descending order
- For each year, get the top 10 countries
- For each country, count how many times it appears on the top-10 list
- Sort the result descendingly

These are chaining methods so the output the previous step becomes the input of the next step.